# bottle.py: globally modify (rewrite) request path for testing a web-application?

Tags: python, bottle

I am setting up [bottle.py](https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/) with [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) run with `$ uwsgi --http :1024 --wsgi-file app.py`. 
`app.py`contains the default:

```
import bottle
application = bottle.default_app()
```

and lots of route decorators and functions such as:

```
@bottle.route('/<A>/<B>')
def somedef():
    return bottle.template(...)
```

This is temporarily being served from http://example.com/secret_URL/, which of course causes `<A>` to always be parsed as "secret_URL".

How can the URL be modified ("rewrite", strip the "secret_URL/") so that the web application, i.e. bottle does not "see" it?

I have found [`add_hook`](https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#bottle.Bottle.add_hook) but so far I have not been able to modify the path of the [request](https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest):

```
@bottle.hook('before_request')
def test():
    bottle.request.url = bottle.request.url.replace("secret_URL/","")
```

The reason becomes clear:

> The Request class wraps a WSGI environment and provides helpful
>   methods to parse and access form data, cookies, file uploads and other
>   metadata. **Most of the attributes are read-only**.

The docs also state:

> Adding new attributes to a request actually adds them to the environ
>   dictionary (as ‘bottle.request.ext.’). This is the recommended
>   way to store and access request-specific data.

and

> environ
>
> The wrapped WSGI environ dictionary. This is the only real attribute. All other attributes actually are read-only properties.

`bottle.request.environ` contains, amongst others, `REQUEST_URI, PATH_INFO, bottle.raw_path, bottle.request, bottle.request.urlparts` and some objects.

Which of these can be written and need to be written for the desired effect?

This then also poses the question of how to handle such links on the client side HTML without changing every single `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error:

```
@bottle.hook('before_request')
def test():
    bottle.request.environ['PATH_INFO'] = bottle.request.environ['PATH_INFO'].replace("secret_URL/","")
```

For the client:

- relative URLs may be a solution, but they can break user copies (unless the browser replaces them) and the application needs to keep track of the path level
- Origin-relative URLs may work with `<base>` (link below)

Related:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Examples
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

---

From https://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/recipes.html?highlight=cache#ignore-trailing-slashes:

> or add a WSGI middleware that strips trailing slashes from all URLs:
>
> ```
> class StripPathMiddleware(object):
>   def __init__(self, app):
>     self.app = app
>   def __call__(self, e, h):
>     e['PATH_INFO'] = e['PATH_INFO'].rstrip('/')
>     return self.app(e,h)
>
> app = bottle.app()
> myapp = StripPathMiddleware(app)
> bottle.run(app=myapp)
> ```

Comment: Also see https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#wsgi-environment for further getter methods/attributes.